# 'PlaintextCorpusReader' object has no attribute 'files'

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I am following an NLTK [tutorial](http://web.mit.edu/6.863/www/fall2012/nltk/ch1-3.pdf) and I got this error in Python interactive shell while the book shows another result. Any idea how to fix this?

```
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.corpus.gutenberg.files()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'PlaintextCorpusReader' object has no attribute 'files'
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tutorial is 6 years old so it is using an old version  `NLTK`. `nltk.corpus.gutenberg.fileids()` will give you the required result.

```
In [22]: nltk.corpus.gutenberg.fileids()
Out[22]: 
['austen-emma.txt',
 'austen-persuasion.txt',
 'austen-sense.txt',
 'bible-kjv.txt',
 'blake-poems.txt',
 'bryant-stories.txt',
 'burgess-busterbrown.txt',
 'carroll-alice.txt',
 'chesterton-ball.txt',
 'chesterton-brown.txt',
 'chesterton-thursday.txt',
 'edgeworth-parents.txt',
 'melville-moby_dick.txt',
 'milton-paradise.txt',
 'shakespeare-caesar.txt',
 'shakespeare-hamlet.txt',
 'shakespeare-macbeth.txt',
 'whitman-leaves.txt']
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The tutorial shows in the beginning of Google search and is from MIT so I thought they kind of manage it.

Comment: No worries, you're welcome. I just had a quick look and saw the last revision was December 2008 so I imagine it is not maintained but I could be wrong.