# Tokenization and lemmatization for TF-IDF use for bunch of txt files using NLTK library

Tags: python, text, nlp, nltk, text-analysis

Doing the text analysis of italian text (tokenization, lemmalization) for future use of TF-IDF technics and constructing clusters based on that. For preprocessing I use NLTK and for one text file everything is working fine:

```
import nltk
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer

it_stop_words = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('italian')

lmtzr = WordNetLemmatizer()

with open('3003.txt', 'r' , encoding="latin-1") as myfile:
    data=myfile.read()

word_tokenized_list = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(data)

word_tokenized_no_punct = [str.lower(x) for x in word_tokenized_list if x not in string.punctuation]

word_tokenized_no_punct_no_sw = [x for x in word_tokenized_no_punct if x not in it_stop_words]

word_tokenized_no_punct_no_sw_no_apostrophe = [x.split("'") for x in word_tokenized_no_punct_no_sw]
word_tokenized_no_punct_no_sw_no_apostrophe = [y for x in word_tokenized_no_punct_no_sw_no_apostrophe for y in x]

word_tokenize_list_no_punct_lc_no_stowords_lemmatized = [lmtzr.lemmatize(x) for x in word_tokenized_no_punct_no_sw_no_apostrophe]
```

But the question is that I need to perform the following to bunch of .txt files in the folder. For that I'm trying to use possibilities of `PlaintextCorpusReader()`:

```
from nltk.corpus.reader.plaintext import PlaintextCorpusReader

corpusdir = 'reports/'

newcorpus = PlaintextCorpusReader(corpusdir, '.txt')
```

Basically I can not just apply `newcorpus` into the previous functions because it's an object and not a string. So my questions are:

1. How should the functions look like (or how should I change the existing ones for a distinct file) for doing tokenization and lemmatization for a corpus of files (using `PlaintextCorpusReader()`)
2. How would the TF-IDF approach (standard sklearn approach of `vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()` will look like in `PlaintextCorpusReader()`

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your question can be answered by reading: this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25352211/plaintextcorpusreader-object-has-no-attribute-files), this [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42819535/nltk-plaintextcorpusreader-sents-and-paras-functions-not-working) and [TfidfVectorizer docs][3]. For completeness, I wrapped the answers below:

---

First, you want to get the files ids, by [the first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25352211/plaintextcorpusreader-object-has-no-attribute-files) you can get them as follows:

```
ids = newcorpus.fileids()
```

Then, based on [the second quetion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42819535/nltk-plaintextcorpusreader-sents-and-paras-functions-not-working) you can retrieve documents' words, sentences or paragraphs:

```
doc_words = []
doc_sents = []
doc_paras = []
for id_ in ids:
    # Get words
    doc_words.append(newcorpus.words(id_))
    # Get sentences
    doc_sents.append(newcorpus.sents(id_))
    # Get paragraph
    doc_paras.append(newcorpus.paras(id_))
```

Now, on the *ith* position of `doc_words`, `doc_sents` and `doc_paras` you have all words, sentences and paragraphs (respectively) for every document in the corpus.

For **tf-idf** you probably just want the words. Since [`TfidfVectorizer.fit`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.fit)'s method gets an iterable which yields `str`, unicode or file objects, you need to either transform your documents (array of tokenized words) into a single string, or use a similar approach to [this one](http://www.davidsbatista.net/blog/2018/02/28/TfidfVectorizer/). The latter solution uses a dummy tokenizer to deal directly with arrays of words.

You can also pass your own tokenizer to `TfidVectorizer` and use PlaintextCorpusReader simply for file reading.

Comment: For removing punctuation and stopwords I often use list comprehension. With a quick research I found this [gist](https://gist.github.com/ameyavilankar/10347201) with other approaches, such as using `filter`. I guess that for lemmatizing you can also use list comprehension. I find a bit odd you cant lemmatize an array of words directly... You can wrap all this in one line such as:
`words = [lemmatize(word) for word in words if word not in stopwords and len(word) > 1]`

Comment: Can't do that because StreamBackedCorpusView objects are unhashable

Comment: Don't see where you're using `StreamBackedCorpusView` you can do what i described on my last comment using the `doc_words` from my answer, you can also see the last link I provided